# Cut and paste multiple lines in vim

Tags: vim

I'm running vim 7.3 on a Mac 10.7.2 and I'm having some trouble cutting and pasting several lines.

On my old Linux setup (which was stolen so I don't know versions), I could type "dd" multiple times and then "p" would yank all of them back. For example: type: "dd dd" and two lines would be deleted.  Now type "p" and *both* lines are pasted back into the buffer.

I know I can accomplish what I want by typing "2dd", and then "p" - but I would like to be able to "dd"-out lines without counting the number of lines ahead of time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not to count lines ahead use "relativenumbers" to display line numbers relative to your cursor. And starting with 7.4 setting both "numbers" and "relativenumbers" makes the line number where your cursor is absolute and the others relative, getting the best of both worlds. Then it's easier to do like @Giovanni suggested d2d (for two lines).

Comment: This is awesome, but for anyone trying this it is actually "number" and "relativenumber", not "numbers" and "relativenumbers" :)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Have you considered using [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html)?

You could just go:

- Press `V`
- Select everything you want to cut without counting
- Press `d`
- Go to where you want to paste
- Press `p`

This should yield approximately half as many keystrokes as the `dd` method since you press one key per line rather than two. Bonus points if you use `5j` (or similar) to select multiple lines at a time.

Comment: I was gonna say that I didn't want to do this because I "liked" my old work-flow. But, I just tried it and it's way better. Thanks!

Comment: every time I come back to this answer to look up how to cut and paste I want to upvote it again :)

Comment: Selecting next 5 lines with 5j really helped.. Initially I was not aware that all the h, j, k, l navigation keys work in Visual mode.

Comment: when I copy lines from another editor, and try to paste in vim with 'p' it just adds a new line.

Comment: this is a traditional way, and it's *not fast*.

Comment: how to copy instead of cut?

Answer (score 47):

You could type:

```
d<n>d
```

where `<n>` is the number of lines that you want to cut, and then you could paste them with:

```
p
```

For example, to cut and paste 3 lines:

```
d3d
p
```

Answer (score 22):

To cut and paste by line numbers (do `:set number` to see the line numbers), for lines x to y do:

```
:x,yd
```

or if your cursor is already on line x, do

```
:,yd
```

Then go to where you want to paste and press `p`

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is close enough to what you're trying, but one thing you could do is use a specific register, and capitalize your register name. That tells vim to append to the register rather than replace it, so if you have the lines:

```
one
two
three
```

you can enter

```
"qdd
"Qdd
"Qdd
```

and then subsequently if you enter

```
"qp
```

it will paste back the original lines

Comment: From the question, it looks like it was mapped to `d`.

Answer (score 5):

To copy and paste 4 lines:

`y4y` (with the cursor on the starting line you wanna copy)

`p`   (with cursor on the line you wanna paste after)

Comment: `without counting the number of lines ahead of time.` This solution doesn't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ben S. that this is the preferred way to accomplish this but if you are just looking to replicate your old behavior you can remap `dd` to append to a specified register, and then map `p` to paste from that register and clear it.
This will have the disadvantage of causing `p` to only work with things deleted using dd (using `d}` to delete to the end of the paragraph would not put the text in the correct register to be pasted later).

Add the following to your vimrc

```
noremap dd "Ddd             "Appends the contents of the current line into register d
noremap p "dp:let @d=""<CR> "Pastes from register d and then clears it out
```

if you don't want pasting to clear out the contents of the register

```
noremap p "dp               "Paste from register d
```

but this will cause that register to grow without ever clearing it out